# brew install cassandra12 fails on Mac

Tags: macos, cassandra, homebrew

When I try to install `cassandra12` on my Mac using:

```
brew install cassandra12
```

It fails with:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/versions/cassandra12" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Updating, uninstalling and re-installing brew didn't help either. Can somebody help me with how to fix this issue?

Note: '`brew search cassandra`' shows `cassandra21` and `cassandra22`. I need `cassandra12` specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra 1.2 was [removed from home-brew versions about a month ago](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/pull/1274).

[zzatking](https://github.com/zzatking) posted the [following on the pull request](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/pull/1274#issuecomment-223403003)

> If anyone really needs a version that was removed due to this pull
>   request, you can find it by following these steps:
>
> 1. Click the commit above related to your software (e.g. cassandra*)
> 2. Find the formula you desire (e.g. cassandra12.rb)
> 3. Click "View" for that formula
> 4. Click "Raw" for the source
> 5. Copy the URL
> 6. Run `brew install <URL>`